# Jquery SlideToggle Multiple Divs with same classes

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I created a Read More / Less Toggle in Jquery.
Now i need some help, I'm a Beginner in Jquery and don't know all functions.

My Code: http://jsfiddle.net/U6yk2/

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor      invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<div class="toggle">
<div class="more" style="display:none">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
</div>
<div class="less">
<a class="button-read-more button-read" href="#read">Mehr lesen</a>
<a class="button-read-less button-read" href="#read">Weniger anzeigen</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".more").hide();
jQuery('.button-read-more').click(function(){
     jQuery('.less').toggleClass('active');
     $(".more").slideDown("1000");
});
jQuery('.button-read-less').click(function(){
     jQuery('.less').removeClass('active');
     $(".more").slideUp("1000");
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.less.active .button-read-more {
display: none;
}

.button-read-less{
display: none;
}

.less.active .button-read-less{
display: block;
}

.more{
margin-top: 10px;
}

.more p{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

My target is now, to have multiple Toggles but with the same classes.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative elements like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".more").hide();
    $('.button-read-more').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.less').addClass('active');
        $(this).closest(".less").prev().stop(true).slideDown("1000");
    });
    $('.button-read-less').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.less').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest(".less").prev().stop(true).slideUp("1000");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LHcgp/)

Answer (score 0):

update your code -  it will toggle correctly .

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").hide();
    jQuery('.button-read-more').click(function(){
        jQuery('.less').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).slideDown("1000");
    });
    jQuery('.button-read-less').click(function(){
        jQuery('.less').removeClass('active');
        $(this).slideUp("1000");
    });
});
```

Comment: It toggle corrects, but I want multiple Toggles with the same classes. I want this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U6yk2/1/)

Comment: What does mean toggle with same classes ? you want to expand single item on link click or you want to expand all items on any link click?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the current paragrpah and expand it accordingly.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").hide();
    jQuery('.button-read-more').click(function(){
         var $par=$(this).closest('.toggle')
         $par.find('.less').toggleClass('active');
         $par.find(".more").slideDown("1000");
    });
    jQuery('.button-read-less').click(function(){
         var $par=$(this).closest('.toggle')
         $par.find('.less').removeClass('active');
         $par.find(".more").slideUp("1000");
    });
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gZz9x/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()` method to work only in current context. Update your code to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".more").hide();
    jQuery('.button-read-more').click(function(){
        var toggle = $(this).closest('.toggle');
        toggle.find('.less').toggleClass('active');
        toggle.find('.more').slideDown("1000");
    });
    jQuery('.button-read-less').click(function(){
        var toggle = $(this).closest('.toggle');
        toggle.find('.less').removeClass('active');
        toggle.find('.more').slideUp("1000");
    });
});
```